# How to print aem form through dor template?

Tags: forms, aem

I want to print the aem form(through dor template) just like we download it using dor template.             For Reference Install the package from this and install and open the form when you click on submit button the pdf will get downloaded i need to print the same pdf when i click on the submit

Comment: https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-learn/forms/adaptive-forms/document-of-record-api-tutorial-use.html for more information.

Comment: What have you tried so far?